# Getting extra trailing spaces in each column when using lpad in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am running below query using a shell script to get data from oracle.

```
set heading off;
set COLSEP ",";
set echo off;
set FEEDBACK off;
set pages 0;
set tab off;
set linesize 10000;
SELECT nvl(lpad(ID1,9,' '),'         '),
ID2,
lpad(ID3,11,' '),
nvl(ID4,'         ')
FROM ENTMST.T_DB_ENTITY;
quit;
```

And getting output like below.

```
197329691                           ,197329691,  197329691                                 ,197329691
```

for example, 3rd column lpad is working fine for value 197329691 but i am getting extra space after that. How i can remove those?

Comment: what is the result of `SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 FROM ENTMST.T_DB_ENTITY` 

Just to check the normal output

Comment: What is the datatype of the ID fields? `CHAR` perhaps?

Comment: Data type is char(9) and normal output is below.
197329691,197329691,197329691,197329691

Comment: @user3760704 What RDBMS are You using? the Querry seems correct.

Comment: I am running it through sqlplus command on oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Add aliases for each column:

```
SELECT NVL(LPAD(ID1,9,' '),'         ') ID1,
  ID2 ID2,
  LPAD(ID3,11,' ') ID3,
  NVL(ID4,'         ') ID4
FROM ENTMST.T_DB_ENTITY;
```

Set the sql plus column width preceding the select statement:

```
   COL id1 FORMAT A9
   COL id2 FORMAT A9
   COL id3 FORMAT A9
   COL id4 FORMAT A9
```

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap it like this:

```
RTRIM( lpad(ID3,11,' '))
```

Comment: RTRIM is not helping. getting same output.